# How to render dynamic Angular custom elements

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm working on projects that implemented Angular web component concept [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

Now we have only 2 or 3 elements that will display dynamically base on the user's input.
After the user finished the form, the main.js file of specific element will get downloaded and it will show in the place that be in the template. By this, everything is just fine.

The example code will let you see the problem here:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplay">
    <element-a *ngIf="inpt='a'" [inputForm]="inputForm">
    <element-b *ngIf="inpt='b'" [inputForm]="inputForm">
    <element-c *ngIf="inpt='c'" [inputForm]="inputForm">
    ...
<div>
```

The problem is, in the future we will have around 30 elements and it's not a good idea to always rebuild the parent application every time we have a new element.

So, I would like to know if it's any way to do something like, read the list in a configure file and do something like.

```
<div *ngFor="let elementName of elementList">
   <element-{{elementName}} *ngIf="inpt='elementName'" [inputForm]="inputForm">
<div>
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://formly.dev/.

Comment: You can look at the Angular Way to do it here [https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: @MaximeChevallier  The `ViewContainerRef` cannot being used. The parent project doesn't contain a component of any child element.

Comment: I'm... not sure how possible this is without doing some wild stuff with `ComponentFactory` and `ViewContainer`, and passing the component you need (`<element-b>`) as an `@Input()`. (Angular Material does some stuff like this interally with their `Dialog` component, and it isn't pretty.) Could you maybe use `ng-content` instead?

Comment: Maybe `ngComponentOutlet` will work for you (Again, passing the component you need via `@Input()`), or if not, you might be stuck using [ViewContainer](https://dev.to/railsstudent/render-dynamic-components-in-angular-using-viewcontainerref-160h).

Answer (score 0):

To keep things completely dynamic it might prove simpler to just manipulate the DOM.

So you can use something like:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly doc: Document) {}

const e = this.doc.createElement(`element-${element}`);
// Set up e's attributes here and add it to the DOM
```

This will, however, require extra work to link it to event handlers (e.g. by using rxjs's `fromEvent()`) and to monitor property changes.

Also, to mimic `*ngIf` you'll have to make it conditional.

Comment: By this, it won't let you to assign input, output of the component.

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading multiple web components, you may need to loop the components in .ts file instead of .html file.

Update html template code like this:

```
<div id="parentElement"></div>
```

in .ts file load components like this:

```
const parentElement = document.getElementById("parentElement");
for(let element of elementList) {
 const childElement = document.createElement(element.selector); // element.selector will be the name of the custom element defined. Eg:. app-custom-element-1
 // pass inputs like this.
 childElement.input1 = "abc";
 childElement.input2 = "abcde";
 // for outputs
 childElement.addEventListener('sampleOutpur', (data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
 });
 parentElement.appendChild(childElement);
}
```

Comment: I have to pass input, output of each component, not just a tag.

Comment: in above example, input1 and input2 acts as input variables to your web component.

in your web component you should accept these 2 variables as inputs like


  @Input() input1 : any = false;
  @Input() input2 : any = '';

Answer (score 0):

import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

// Trigger change detection to display the dynamic component
this.changeDetector.detectChanges();